# php mysql form with gtag_report_conversion

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-ads-api

I am trying to get data with form and track Adwords with gtag_report_conversion

My code:

```
                  <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" autocomplete="off">
          <ul class="form-box">
              <li>
                 <input name="adi" type="text" id="adi" class="form-text" required="required" placeholder="Adınız" />
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input name="mesaj" type="text" id="mesaj" class="form-text" required="required" placeholder="Soyadınız" />
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input name="telefon" type="tel"  id="telefon" class="form-text" required="required" placeholder="Telefon" />
              </li>
              <li>
                 <input name="mail" type="email" id="mail" class="form-text" required="required" placeholder="E-Posta" />
              </li>
              <li class="izin">
                 <input type="checkbox" required="required" checked> <a href="javascript:;" data-fancybox="modal" data-src="#bilgilendirme-modal">İletişim sözleşmesini </a> okudum,
                 <br> kabul ediyorum.
              </li>

           </ul>
        </form>
        <button  type="submit" name="submit" form="form1" class="form-submit" value="Submit" onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('http://localhost/thanks.php');">GÖNDER</button>
```

I am saving the data at mysql.

This is the code in same page.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$adi = $_POST["adi"];
$telefon = $_POST["telefon"];
$mail = $_POST["mail"];
$mesaj = $_POST["mesaj"];
$tarih = date("d.m.Y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO iletisim_formu (adi,telefon,mail,mesaj,tarih,ip) VALUES ('" . $adi. "','" . $telefon. "','" . $mail. "','" . $mesaj. "','" . $tarih. "','" . $ip. "')");
$stmt->execute();
}
```

When I write in button

onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('http://localhost/thanks.php');"

it is going to thanks page but not save to db.
When I remmove it, it save to db but I couldn't use gtag.

What is wrong?

How can I do correctly?

Comment: There's no point of using prepared statements if you still concatenating the values in your query. Take a look at the [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) section of the PDO documentation.

Comment: You ommited the `gtag_report_conversion` function, but I'm assuming that it redirects to another page. If this is the case, the redirection might be happening before the form is submitted.